# Where is Jsonstore data of ibm worklight stored?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Does ibm worklight use local storage for json store?where is json store data stored on the android /ios/windows device?

Answer (score 2):

From: [JSONStore overview](http://ttp://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html)

> JSONStore is a lightweight, document-oriented storage system that is
>   included as a feature of IBM® MobileFirst Platform Foundation, and
>   enables persistent storage of JSON documents. Documents in an
>   application are available in JSONStore even when the device that is
>   running the application is offline.
>   ...
>   ...
>   JSONStore is similar to technologies such as LocalStorage, Indexed DB,
>   Cordova Storage API, Cordova File API, and MobileFirst Encrypted
>   Cache. The table shows how some features that are provided by
>   JSONStore compare with other technologies.

The data is stored in the application's sandbox.

Comment: but where it is stored on the device i want the folder where it is stored

Comment: i am testing it and at times i have to clear the data jus like we clear history so if you could tell me where it is stored it would really help

Comment: Clear it how? JSONStore provides API to clear the storage. As for the sandbox, it is different for each app - learn about Cordova Filesystem API to understand how to reach it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_troubleshooting_overview.html). For example, on Android it's stored here: `/data/data/com.<app-name>/databases/wljsonstore/<jsonstore-username>.sqlite`.

Comment: You mean android/data folder on the device i have seen it there i couldn find anything of that sort it has cache files folder which is blank for that partcicular app